# How to faden/blacken image on scroll

Tags: java, android, scroll, background, fade

I didn't find how I could fade an image when scrolled (vertical). The background image would gradualy become black when user scrolls down and end up totaly black near the end of the image

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, but you forgot to add on which platform you want to do this. Html and css? Or VB6? Or WPF? Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: Hey, really sorry i'm speaking about java/android

Comment: One way to consider is to apply a layer on the background and apply a darkened alpha ontop of the image controlled based on the scroll amount. Much easier than actually darkening the image and possibly less expensive in terms of CPU utilization.